# How can I use DirectoryEntry in SignInManager?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I've create my company web using ASP.NET using DirectoryEntry method to authenticated that user who logged in is a member of company. In case of IT admin didn't allow my IIS server to join domain, so I cannot use the direct Windows Authentication method.

By using just a simple function I've got from the stackoverflow (Thanks to the original coder)

```
Function AuthenticateUser(user As String, pass As String) As Boolean
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
    Try
        'run a search using those credentials.  
        'If it returns anything, then you're authenticated
        Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(de)
        ds.FindOne()
        Return True
    Catch
        'otherwise, it will crash out so return false
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

After I tried moving to C# ASP.NET MVC. I just don't have any ideas how to modify the simple DirectoryEntry to the ApplicationSignInManager method ?

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
}
```

I didn't want users to register to my web. How can I modify the SignInManager to just using their username and password and send them to DirectorySearch ?